# Is there any way to delete previously defined vertices in feynmf?

Tags: feynman, feynmf, feynmp

I'm trying to create feynman diagrams programmatically, and frequently require the need to remove individual vertices that were previously created with the fmfn or fmfcyclen commands. This is so that I don't end up with diagrams that look like this:

[image]

but rather look like this:

[image]
Is there any way to do this? I don't know metapost/metafont, but possibly can this be done with an fmfiset or fmfcmd?

Complete code example below (the commented out line shows what I would like once the offending vertices are deleted, and produces the normal looking image above):

```
\documentclass[border=2.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}


\begin{document}


\begin{fmffile}{simple}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(450,320)

  \fmftop{ti,tf}
  \fmfbottom{bi,bf}
  \fmf{fermion}{ti,t1,tf}
  \fmf{fermion}{bi,b1,bf}
  \fmffreeze

  \fmfcyclen{plain, left=1/2}{v}{5}
%%   \fmfcyclen{plain, left=1/2}{v}{2}                                                                                                                                                                
  \fmf{photon}{t1,v[1]}
  \fmf{photon}{v[2],b1}

    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}


\end{document}
```

Note that another potential workaround would be to be able to create a smooth arc across the multiple vertices shown in the first image, but I have not come across a solution for this (I am aware of the fmfpoly command, which doesn't help).

Comment: Can't you just correct the program that is producing them?

Comment: Theoretically, but in practice with great difficulty. The above is an example to illustrate the point. The actual program (too large to paste above) is meant to programmatically generate random feynman diagrams meeting certain criteria, and due to the randomization, sometimes there will be vertices that are not connected to anything, which causes the above visualization problems.